# How to smoothen and dissolve the output image and how to calculate the pixel areas of different classes in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, area

I am doing supervised classification of 5 different classes, I tried the code suggested in GEE tutorial but I can't able to understand the way they did. I am attaching my code here. Could someone guide me how to calculate the area of different classes? And I want the area of my study region only it is attached as a n asset (tri).

Can we extract our study region (tri - shapefile) from the Landsat image (mosaic)?

Here is the link to my map 
https://code.earthengine.google.com/037ea5a6e8240d4d292f0149e1fb996e

Here is my code:

```
// filter image classification
var image= ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')

  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate('2013-02-02','2017-02-02')
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
  .first());
print (image);


var Trivandrum = ee.Image ('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_144054_20140126');
var Trivandrum1 = ee.Image ('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_143054_20150122');

var mosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([Trivandrum,Trivandrum1]).mosaic();
var composite = {
  bands: ['B2','B3','B4'],
  gamma: 1,
  max: 0.80,
  min: 0.04
};

Map.addLayer(tri,{},"triv");
Map.addLayer(mosaic,{min:10,max:200},"mosaic");

var newfc = urban.merge(agriculture).merge(waterbodies).merge(wetland_coastal).merge(forest);
print(newfc, 'newfc');

// Select the bands to be used in training
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5','B6','B7'];

// Sample the input imagery to get a FeatureCollection of training data.
var training = mosaic.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: newfc,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 30  // should reflect the scale of your imagery, the scale is 30 meters
});
var trained = ee.Classifier.cart().train(training, 'landcover', bands);

// Classify the image with the same bands used for training.
var classified_ = mosaic.select(bands).classify(trained);

var palette = [
  'FF0000', // urban
  '008000', // agriculture
  '0000FF', //  water bodies
  'E3BC1E',   //coastal areas
  '1EE363', // forest 

];

Map.setCenter(76.98244, 8.4686, 11); 

Map.addLayer (mosaic, composite); 
Map.addLayer (classified_, {min: 0, max: 5, palette: palette}, 'Land Use Classification');

var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
          [[[76.2593, 8.8932],
          [76.4076, 8.0402],
          [77.314, 8.915],
          [77.4897, 8.2686]]]);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified_,
  description: 'Trivandrum_mosaic',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  folder: 'GEE',
  maxPixels: 10000000000000
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to the end of your code.  You'll need to define `geometry` to be your ROI and ensure that it overlaps the classified image:

```
var options = {
  lineWidth: 1,
  pointSize: 2,
  hAxis: {title: 'Classes'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Area m^2'},
  title: 'Area by class',
  series: {
    0: { color: 'red'},
    1: { color: 'green'},
    2: { color: 'blue'}
  }
};

var areaChart = ui.Chart.image.byClass({
  image: ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(classified),
  classBand: 'classification', 
  region: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum()
}).setOptions(options)
  .setSeriesNames(['urban', 'vegetation', 'water']);
print(areaChart);
```

Comment: You are telling like i need to define roi as a geometry?

Comment: and sir while running the program with the code you have given it shows the error such that :Error generating chart: Image.reduceRegion: Too many pixels in the region. Found 11494060, but only 10000000 allowed.
Image.reduceRegion: Too many pixels in the region. Found 11494060, but only 10000000 allowed.   How can i avoid this error?

Comment: Also how to extract only the trivandrum region with the shape file (table) from the landsat image. I am attaching the link :https://code.earthengine.google.com/4f3cf9a0b6f5628233d9dbcb80a9c389

Comment: Your region is too big.  You'll have to make it smaller or use https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_region followed by charting the values directly using https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/charts_array_values